# what is the parameter used to get service description along with listing it

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

i want to retrieve the windows services filtered with description included along. i am able to give condition with get-service, but unable to pull the description of the service along with the same output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service description isn't included in `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`. One can, however, use `Management.ManagementObject` to read description. Here's [a sample](https://tahirhassan.blogspot.com/2017/03/powershell-get-services-description.html) from the web. In case of link rot, code is like so,

```
# Get Adobe updater service
$svc = [Management.ManagementObject]::new("Win32_Service.Name='AdobeARMservice'")
# Print description
$svc.Description
Adobe Acrobat Updater keeps your Adobe software up to date.
# Release objects' resources
$svc.Dispose()
```

To get all the desired services, pipe `Get-Service` filtered to a foreach loop

```
get-service | % {
  $svc = [Management.ManagementObject]::new($("Win32_Service.Name='" + $_.name +"'"))
  $_.name +" " + $svc.Description
  $svc.Dispose()
}
```